# Hashing an unordered_map of pair<pair<int,int>,pair<int,int>>

Tags: c++, templates, hash, unordered-map

I have defined the following types

```
typedef pair<int,int> point ;
typedef pair<int,int> fraction ; 
typedef pair<fraction,fraction> line ;
```

with a custom hash function as follows -

```
struct hash_pair { 
    template <class T1, class T2>
    size_t operator() (const pair<T1, T2> &pair) const
    {
        return hash<T1>()(pair.first) ^ hash<T2>()(pair.second);
    }
};
```

I've declared two maps as follows -

```
unordered_map<point, int, hash_pair> points ;
unordered_map<line, int, hash_pair> lines ;
```

I also have two variables `point p` and `line l` that I assign appropriately. When I performed `points.find(p)`, it works properly. However, when I use `lines.find(l)`, I'm obtaining endless lines of errors as follows -

```
solution.cpp: In instantiation of 'size_t hash_pair::operator()(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) const [with T1 = std::pair<int, int>; T2 = std::pair<int, int>; size_t = long unsigned int]':
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1384:16:   required from 'std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::__hash_code std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::_M_hash_code(const _Key&) const [with _Key = std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >; _Value = std::pair<const std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >, int>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _H1 = hash_pair; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::__hash_code = long unsigned int]'
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:1417:19:   required from 'std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >; _Value = std::pair<const std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >, int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >, int> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> > >; _H1 = hash_pair; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >, int>, false, true>; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::key_type = std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >]'
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/unordered_map.h:921:29:   required from 'std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::iterator std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >; _Tp = int; _Hash = hash_pair; _Pred = std::equal_to<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> > >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >, int> >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::iterator = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >, int>, false, true>; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >]'
solution.cpp:105:30:   required from here
solution.cpp:11:16: error: use of deleted function 'std::hash<std::pair<int, int> >::hash()'
   15 |         return hash<T1>()(pair.first) ^ hash<T2>()(pair.second);
      |
```

There are two errors marked on `lines.find(l)`, and another one on `return hash<T1>()(pair.first) ^ hash<T2>()(pair.second);`

Can anyone please help me out how I perform regular use of unordered_map on the `pair<pair<int,int>,pair<int,int>>` ? Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect `hash_pair<line>´ to work without `hash<pair<int,int>>`?

Comment: Right. Since T1 and T2 represent arbitrary types, I'd assumed that C++ would automatically expand a <fraction,fraction> to a <pair<int,int>,pair<int,int>> and it would work fine. I'm not strong with C++'s type system and templates. Thanks!

Comment: @AnweshBhattacharya That _is_ actually what happens, and that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with nested pairs would be to recurse and provide an overload that exits when the argument is not a pair.  For example:

```
struct hash_pair { 
    template <class T1, class T2>
    size_t operator() (const pair<T1, T2> &pair) const
    {
        return (*this)(pair.first) ^ (*this)(pair.second);
    }

    template <class T>
    size_t operator() (const T &v) const
    {
        return hash<T>()(v);
    }
};
```

(Of course, simple xor is not a great way to hash a pair.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your code snippet fixed my problem perfectly!
Would you recommend any resource for creating good hash functions, especially for custom data-types? I'd appreciate it. Thanks again!